# Detecting URL changes using Delphi and TChromium

Tags: delphi, tchromium

I am using dcef3 and Delphi XE2. When the URL changes I would like to detect it and show a delphi message displaying the new URL. Can this be achieved? I am trying to use the URL to pass delphi some commands to execute.

Thank you for your help and apologies for my bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are looking for the [`OnAddressChange`](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/projects/%28default%29/CefDisplayHandler.html#OnAddressChange) event. This event is fired when the frame's address has changed. The new URL of the frame you can get from the `url` parameter.